# KIVY start background auto-restart service

Tags: python, kivy

I want to start a service in the background when the user clicks on a button. I use python and KIVY and my application is for Android devices.
My problem is that I want the service I run in the background to restart automatically when the phone reboots. I saw in the p4a documentation that I should put :sticky:foreground in the buildozer spec and add the permission.
I've seen in the p4a documentation that you have to put :sticky:foreground in the buildozer spec and add the permission, but my service starts when I click on the button but when I restart my smartphone. It doesn't launch anymore (I don't have the notification that informs me of its presence).

Comment: It's unspecific and unclear. See [ask]. Research more on the Android service and ask a specific question. By the 'auto-restart service', you mean a service started without a user interaction from a foreground app? That's a bad behavior and basically impossible in Android, although there exists a trick such as registering as a accessibility service.

Comment: I modify my question, I Hope I am more clear.

Comment: Again, research more on the Android service. When the system reboots, a service will not start without a user interaction from a foreground app.

Comment: Ok I tought it was possible.But how does the apps like Gmail to send notifications when we reboot the phone without a user interaction ?

Comment: Gmail uses a push service(Firebase). The privileged Google play service app deals that. It's enough. Research by yourself.